# Can we customise the html content editor in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, angular5, froala

I'm new to angular, currently, I'm working on angular 5, I have a requirement that I need to customize the HTML content editor like when i
right click on selected content in editor need to give the custom menu to right click and need to hide some content or disable particular content in the editor, I'm using Froala and CKEditor in angular 5.

What I have tried is, given the read-only option to the editor, but it is applying to the whole editor, and tried custom context menu with this we can able to create the menu with static content.

```
app.component.html

<ckeditor 
 [(ngModel)]="ckeditorContent"
 [config]="ckeConfig" 
 [readonly]="false"
 debounce="500" 
 (change)="onChange($event)"
 ng-right-click="someFunction()" 
 menu-items="menuItems"
></ckeditor>

**app.components.ts**

  import { Component } from '@angular/core';


  @Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']  
  })
  export class AppComponent {
        ckeditorContent: string = '<p>Some html</p>';

        public menuItems: Object = [
           { text: "Menu Item 1", //menu option text
             disabled: true //No click event. Grayed out option.
           },
           {
             text:"Menu Item 2", 
             disabled: false
           }
        ];

        someFunction(){

            console.log('test');
        }  

        onChange(test){

        }
   }


app.module.ts

  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { CKEditorModule } from 'ng2-ckeditor';


  import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
  import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
  @NgModule({
     declarations: [
      AppComponent
     ],
     imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      CKEditorModule,
      FormsModule
     ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Need suggestions, please let me know can we do that or not, if yes how can I achieve.

Comment: can you show us so far what you've done

Comment: please check i have edited my code

Comment: Hello anyone there to help me please